# Visual Studio Code não sugere métodos e classes do Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, visual-studio-code

Se eu digitar o código e passar para o Unity, o Unity executa o código normalmente, mas o Visual Studio não está reconhecendo o Unity (como dá para ver nas cores da foto abaixo), o que deixa muito dificil programar.
Na instalação, eu deixei a caixa de "Desenvolvimento de Jogos com Unity" marcada, junto com "Desenvolvimento para Descktop com .NET".
Já desistalei essa versão e instalei de novo. O problema continua.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A imagem é sobre o VS Enterprise, não sobre o VSCode, mas de qualquer forma para usar Unity no VScode instale as extensões:

- [Unity tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobiah.unity-tools)
- [Debugger for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug) (essa geralmente instala sozinha quando instala o Unity tools)

Aperte no VSCode Ctrl+Shift+X ou vá no menu lateral:

[image: extensões unity para VSCode]

Lembrando que se o editor padrão que abre for outro para trocar você deve ir em Edit > Preferences > External tools

[image: Trocar o editor padrão no unity]

Depois vá em <kbd>Window</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager</kbd> e digite no campo Vscode e atualize ou instale o pacote do vscode:

[image: pacote do vscode]

A esta altura já deve estar tudo ok e funcionando no VSCode (talvez tenha que fechar o VSCode uma vez), resultado:

[image: autocomplete classes unity no vscode]

---

### Instalando snippets para unity no VSCode

Pode ser que talvez você não estivesse falando disso, mas sim de estruturas semi-prontas/sugestões que o editor pode fornecer, se for esse o caso tem que instalar a extensão:

- [unity-code-snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kleber-swf.unity-code-snippets)

Mesmo processo, Ctrl+Shift+X ou vá no menu lateral:

[image: snippets para unity no vscode]

Comment: Deu certo! Mais especificamente quando fui em em Package Manager e cliquei em atualizar o VS Code. Esse era o problema. Obrigado

Comment: @GustavoGLD blz. Marque a resposta como correta então: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635